# How to build angular project to compatible with Chrome Extension obfuscation policy

Tags: angularjs, typescript, google-chrome-extension, angular-cli

We have been working on an Angular project with TypeScript (Visual Studio Code). We are deploying this project as Chrome Extension in Google Webstore, it was worked fine, but two days back when we try to re-publish the extension with the latest changes, the Chrome Store reject the request with the below reason.

> Your item did not comply with the following section of our Program
> Policies:
>
> "Content Policies"
>
> Developers must not obfuscate code or conceal functionality of their
> extension. This also applies to any external code or resource fetched
> by the extension package.
>
> Your item was found to have one or more files that does not comply
> with this policy.
>
> Please note that minification is allowed in the following forms:
>
> - Removal of whitespace, newlines, code comments, and block delimiters
> - Shortening of variable and function names
> - Collapsing the number of JavaScript files
>
> For more information, please review these recommended Minification
> Techniques for Google Developers.

We are build our angular project with **ng build** command.
Our environment parameters:

```
Angular CLI: 1.5.2
Node: 12.13.0
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 5.2.3
... common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms, http
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router

@angular/animations: 5.2.11
@angular/cdk: 5.2.5
@angular/cli: 1.5.2
@angular/material: 5.2.5
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer: 0.0.42
@angular-devkit/core: 0.2.0
@angular-devkit/schematics: 0.0.52
@ngtools/json-schema: 1.1.0
@ngtools/webpack: 1.8.2
@schematics/angular: 0.1.17
typescript-require: 0.2.9-1
typescript: 2.4.2
webpack: 3.8.1
```

Can anyone help us how to build our project so that it will be compatible with Chrome Extension policies?.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting, Sorry to let you down but I'm afraid that's impossible (without authors help) to convert typescript into readable unobfuscated code.
I was looking into that, I'm afraid that your only option is to ask google to review your source code and check sum it but that will be a pain for both you and the reviewer to do every time theres an update to your extension from your side.
Your only realistic option leftout at that point will be to convert your typescript angular project into purejs angular project, using pure javascript is actually not that scary and should technically speed up different parts of the process if not all of the processes all together, a wise man once said that a good javascript developer can write code that is much more efficient and faster than a group of typescript developers, I'm afraid that's true.. the transcription process that occur when typescript compiles into javascript will always generate "machine code" or in other words unreadable obfuscated code, at least from my point of view, this is all purely my opinions based on the knowledge and exprience I gathered from the start of this computer age (Yes I lived through all of it).
So just to be clear, In it's own weird way: typescript is javascript, which means that some of the core codes like database interactions, classes, functions and html can easily be converted into pure javascript without fuz.

Check this out:
https://www.google.com/search?q=convert+angular+typescript+to+javascript